# Why does safari reload the page when I swipe back on iOS?

Tags: ios, django, safari, user-experience

I'm building a webpage with Django. When I want to test the project on safari iOS I try to use the swipe back or the back button, but it doesn't perform the right action, instead it reloads the same page.

I have tested the same swipe in another webpage and it works correctly.

Does anyone know why it happens and how to correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know why this error happened.
I had a function `initialize()` that calls `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);` and inside of the initialize function I had `map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-details"), mapProp);` and a call to a API rest. Inside of the call to the API rest I had the same code `map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-details"), mapProp);`.
For get the bug fixed I deleted the map declaration in the initialize function and kept the one in the Api call.
This was the most weird thing I've seen and it was all the fault of google maps.

**Before**

```
function initialize(){
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-details"), mapProp);
    $.ajax({
        ...,
        success: {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-details"), mapProp);
            ...
        }
    });
}
```

**After**

```
function initialize(){
    $.ajax({
        ...,
        success: {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-details"), mapProp);
            ...
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

---

It sounds like Django may have some javascript on your webpage that is calling a reload() function.  If the same behavior occurs on a desktop browser, you could easily inspect (In Chrome: Right Click > Inspect) the webpage's source code and look for javascript functions that reload the page.  Maybe the reload is part of a Django plugin that you could disable on your site.

Comment: In desktop and android works perfectly, this weird behavior only happens in safari ios.